# Are there any ternary inference rules in propositional logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

Every transformation rule I've seen in the context of propositional logic proofs have an arity of 1-2, with citations looking like

```
...previous
4. x        1,2 Modus Ponens
5. y        3   Double Negation Elimination
```

Are there any transformation rules that show up in logic proofs which operate on more than 2 propositions?

```
...previous
4. x        1,2,3 Some Rule
```

Comment: Yes, [Disjunction Elim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I would suspect there is a way to achieve the same result of Disjunction Elimination using the usual binary inference rules in multiple steps, with Disjunction Elimination just being a shorthand extrapolation of the more primitive inference rules. Is that true?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA while I am asking, is 3 then the maximum arity for transformation rules? Is there even a maximum?

Comment: The "traditional" modern proof system for propositional logic has one rule only: Modus Ponens. But you can simply add new rules (derived ones) based on valid inferences.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you mean all the other inference rules can be derived from Modus Ponens alone? That is interesting. Where can I read more to see the technique? And does this apply to the rules of replacement too? Thanks.

Comment: MP plus axioms... There are many proof systems: from [Hilbert-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems) (many axioms+one rule) to [Natural Deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/) (no axioms and many rules). To read more? A math log textbook, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Some systems define:

**Constructive Dilemma**

$P \lor Q$

$ P \to R$

$Q \to S$

$\therefore R \lor S$

There is also:

**Destructive Dilemma**

$\neg R \lor \neg S$

$ P \to R$

$Q \to S$

$\therefore \neg P \lor \neg Q$

In general and theoretically, you can define inference rules involving any number of statements. In fact, they don’t even have to reflect valid inferences (… though what purpose that would have…). In practice, you’ll never see any involving 4 or more premises though, and even ternary ones are rare.

As Mauro points out in the Comments, theoretically you can do everything with just Modus Ponens and some axioms (which themselves can be seen as inferences based on zero premises). There are even systems (e.g. the Nicod system) where you can prove every propositional truth using a single operator, a single axiom, and s single inference rule.